# impersonation via token stored in a cookie

Tags: asp.net, winapi, impersonation

I want to know more about win32 LogonUser api function. The last parameter is a token which can be used to impersonate a windows identity to execute code on a person's behalf. Say I have a login page where I enter my username, password and domain. When the user submits the page I validate the user by making a call to `LogonUser()` and get a token reference.

I am thinking why not store the token in a cookie and use it at a later stage (perhaps in another page). I just don't know what issues I might have to face upfront...

Can the token expire even if we don't close it properly using the `CloseHandle()` win32 call? Is there any article related with this particular requirement?